# Why Is React Context.Provider Necessary (Or useful)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, datacontext

The reason React has contexts is to allow for multiple sibling components to share a piece of state-data. It is the go-to method for allowing two unrelated components to read/write in shared variables. The reason it is necessary is that React has no way to easily source a data value to multiple screens without actually passing that data between screens. Instead, it allows each screen access to the data when it needs it.

So... The implementation requires that a component be created, called a `Context.Provider` component, and then you have to wrap the components who need access to the shared data inside the `Context.Provider`. But why? Why on earth is that a requirement? `Context`s are designed sharing data between components who aren't hierarchally related, and were required to put the components within a heirarchy to do so?

It would be 100 times more straight forward and just as effective to simply drop the requirement of using a Context.Provider, simple have the `useContext` function give access to a set variable by default:

```
// In ctx.js
import React from 'react';
export default CTX = React.createContext({val: "value"});
```

```
// In compA.js
import CTX from './ctx.js';
import {useContext} from 'react';
function A(props) {
    var [context, setContext] = useContext(CTX);
    console.log(context); //Logs {val: 'value'};
    setContext({val: "newValue"});
}
```

Then later on, assuming component B renders after A:

```
import CTX from './ctx.js';
import {useContext} from 'react';
function B(props) {
    var [context, setContext] = useContext(CTX);
    console.log(context); //Logs {val: 'newValue'};
}
```

The above usage, if it actually worked, solves the task of "sharing data between unrelated components", and is much much simpler than requiring an entire new component be defined in the context file. This solution is better because:
1. No required restructuring of the application. You don't need to wrap components in a provider. 
2. Any Components can just ask for any shared state easily, and they can set the shared state easily.
3. Easier to understand with much less code involved (One line of code for import and one line to initiate the context).
4. Doesn't sacrifice anything. This method allows for easy sharing of state between components, which is the entire reason of contexts in the first place.

Am I crazy? Is there a legitamate reason that we'd absolutely need to wrap our components up in a special component to share data?.. Why can't the shared state just exist independently? Its like they chose a bad solution... Why make every developer wrap there components in another component before using shared state, why not just let the developer use the damned shared state when they need to use it instead of jumping through a hoop? Someone please educate me.

Edit: One answer said that with my described method we wouldn't be able to access multiple contexts with a single component. That is false. It is actually easier with my described method:

```
// In context.js
export const CTX = React.createContext({val: "val"});
export const CTX2 = React.createContext({val2: "val2"});
```

```
// In app.js

function App(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useContext(CTX);
    const [state2, setState2] = userContext(CTX2);
    return (<></>);
}
```

Easy. No need for `Context.Provider`. This is multiple contexts being used in one component, requiring just two calls to useContext versus wrapping your entire application in two nested contexts, which is what is what you have to do with current `Context.Provider` method...

Comment: Well, who cares. It's the specification, maybe old. Could `bad design` an answer to your question?

Comment: I can't answer your question, I wish the React hype will be over, like the Bitcoin hype.

Comment: Just speculating: I think React's main design philosophies are *simplicity* by making context useful in various situations and *explicitness* by forcing you to always have a provider. Yes, there could be *shorter* versions, but does *shorter* mean *better*?

Comment: @ThanhTrung Yes it would! haha

Comment: @JonasWilms Shorter is better so long as the longer version doesn't provide additional functionality that we might want. In this case, the longer version seems to lack *any* usefulness (No features, doesn't make creating the application any easier), since there doesn't seem to be an answer to the question "Why do we have to use Context.Provider?"

Comment: There is. The answer below shows that usecase.

Comment: @JonasWilms Not that I can see? What use case are you talking about. Any of the use cases described in the answer below can be more easily implemented with using `Context.Provider`, if only it was implemented in the way that I described.

Comment: *multiple providers* is different from *multiple contexts*

Comment: 1. multiple providers. 2. scope. I can't summarize it more than that.

Comment: If you're open to migrating to another framework, Svelte's setContext and getContext work exactly as you want, only needing one like of code each.

Answer (score 3):

Mate, answer is simple. React component only re-renders when it's props or state changes. Without Context.Provider component react will never understand when to re-render child components, thus you will have stale, render-blocked components.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose for having a Context Provider wrap around children is to keep track of state and props, read on how state and props between parents and children affect each other. If there was no way for the Context Provider to keep track of its children, how would the components that use the Context be able to update(Changing parent state affects children, so there may be rerendering).

It's also important to understand React's philosophy and it's focus on components, it is a component-based library after all.

Important thing to remember:
Parent state change will affect children, so if state changes in parent, children components will be reevaluated and depending on how your components, state, and data are optimized (memo, callback, etc.) a rerender may occur, thus updating those children components as well.

Answer (score -1):

## Contexts Are Made To Handle All Use Cases

I've since spent more time using Contexts in my applications and have come to realize that `Context.Provider` is quite useful in a variety of situations. My initial complaint has merit in that often times when using `Context` we are simply wanting a variant of state that can be shared between components. In this common use case, `Context.Provider` does indeed requires us to write a bit of unnecessary boilerplate code and requires us to wrap elements in the provider so that they have access to the context.

However any time our shared state becomes a little more complicated having a dedicated `Context.Provider` component can make our lives a lot easier. Here is a use case to consider

## Shared Data From External Sources (Post, Get)

Contexts may allow us to store any code related to the initialization of the shared state within the context itself, resulting in more easily readable and maintainable code. For example, lets say we have some user text posts on our server that are displayed by multiple components within our application, and we would also like for our users to be able to add new posts. All of this can be handled quite neatly within the `Context.Provider`:

```js
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
export const PostsContext = React.createContext([]);

export default PostsContextProvider({children}) {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    
    function fetchPosts() {
        // Here we will fetch the posts from our API, and then set the state
        // stored within the Context.Provider equal to the fetched posts.
        fetch('https://www.fakewebsite.com/api/posts/get', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then((response)=>{
            // Convert response to json
            return response.json();
        }).then((json)=>{
            // json here is the posts we fetched from the server, so we set the state
            // equal to this value. This will update the state within all components
            // that are using the context.
            setPosts(json.posts);
        })
    }

    useEffect(function(){
        // This function will run a single time when the application is started
        fetchPosts();
    },[])

    function addNewPost(post) {
        // This is the function that will be used by the components.
        // First, we will send the new post to the server so that it can store it.
        fetch('https://www.fakewebsite.com/api/posts/post', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({post: post})
        }).then((response)=>{
            if(response.ok) {
                // The server has updated its database with our new post.
                // Now we just need to fetch the posts from the server again to get the updated data.
                fetchPosts();
            } 
        })
    }
    return (
        <PostsContext.Provider
            value={[posts, addNewPost]}
        >
            {children}
        <PostsContext.Provider />
    )
}
```

Notice that the `value` prop we are passing does not actually pass the state setter function directly. Instead, we pass the `addNewPost` function. So, when a component calls `useContext(PostsContext)` they will get the `addNewPost` function. This is extremely useful, it will allow our components to easily add a single post to the shared state, while also handling the server update! Very cool. With the solution I originally proposed, this would be impossible, because we would only ever get a simple state setting function from our `useContext` call.

Now, we must wrap our application in the provider to make it available to all components:

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import PostsContextProvider from './posts_context';
import MyComponent from './my_component';
import MyOtherComponent from './my_other_component';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <PostsContextProvider>
            <MyComponent/>
            <MyOtherComponent/>
        </PostsContextProvider>
    )
}
```

At this point, `MyComponent` and `MyOtherComponent` now have access to the context using the `useContext` hook. It is now extremely simple for the components to access the posts data and also update it with a new post.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {PostContext} from './posts_context';
export default function MyComponent() {
    const [posts, addPost] = useContext(PostsContext); // 'posts' will always be up to date with the latest data thanks to the context.
    
    ...
}
```

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {PostContext} from './posts_context';
export default function MyOtherComponent() {
    const [posts, addPost] = useContext(PostsContext); 
    
    ...
    function handleAddPost(title, text) {
        // Now when this component wants to add a new post, 
        // we just use the `addPost` function from the context.
        addPost({title, text});
    }
    ...
}
```

The beauty of this is that all the code related to the fetching and posting of data can be neatly contained within the provider, separated from the UI code. Each component has easy access to the `posts` data, and when either component adds a new post the other component will be updated with the new data.

## Final Thoughts

This is just scratching the surface of the usefulness of `Context.Provider`. It's easy to imagine using a `Context.Provider` to handle persistent data storage using a method very similar to the above, replacing the `fetch` calls with function that store/fetch persistent data. Or even, some combination of persistent data and fetched data.

Upon revisiting my original question, it actually made me laugh. I was sort of right, there should perhaps be a way to handle simple shared state between components that does not require wrapping components in a provider and does not require any provider code at all. However, providers are just so dang useful in any kind of state management within an application that it is actually probably a good thing to force people to use them for simple shared state, because then they will have to learn about this wonderful tool.